# i want to know how to convert decimal to binary

Tags: python

i have a question.
i don't know why my code is wrong

```
def binary_converter(decimal_number):

     i = decimal_number
     result = ''
         while i >= 0 :
             if i % 2 == 0:
                 result =  result + "0"
                 i = i/2
             else :
                result = "1"
                  i = i/2

     return result.strip()
```

it is my code. what is wrong?

Comment: Wrong order and 1 is different than 0.

Comment: In Python 3, the loop keeps running forever : if you have a positive number and divide repeatedly by 2, the number stays positive

Comment: prefer integer division too.. `i //= 2`

Comment: also, shouldn't it be `result = result + "1"` and `while i > 0`?

Answer (score 1):

There were few little mistakes in your code, olease refer to comments below for details:

```
def binary_converter(decimal_number):
    if decimal_number==0:           #corner case
        return "0";

    i = decimal_number
    result = ""

    while i>0:                      # while i >= 0 : //your loop was running indefinitely
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result =  result + "0"
            i = i//2                # i= i/2 was doing exact division for eg. 3/2=1.5 but 3//2=1
        else :
            result = result + "1"   # there was a silly mistake here
            i = i//2
    return result[::-1].strip()     # ans should be reversed before converting to integer
```

Comment: what is meaning ? : if decimal_number==0:        
                                       return 0;

Comment: @위성률 Since the binary of 0(decimal) is 0(binary), That line is to return 0 if decimal_number is 0.